# Adding image by changing innerHTML leads to WRONG image displayed and Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that contains only one image, say `first.png`. Near the end of the page's body, and way after the first image, I use Javascript to dynamically add a second image as an `img` node. For example:

```
document.getElementById('special-notice').innerHTML = "<br>There's an additional image:<br><img src='second.jpg' width='100px'/>";
```

This worked on my devices. However, a testing user reported seeing `first.png` at the place where `second.jpg` should be, and any further Javascript was not executed, possibly due to an error. The problem disappears after clearing the browser cache (Safari on iPhone).

In what scenarios would a browser display a wrong image?

Comment: Do you want to add image (inside special-notice element), OR to rewrite html content of special-notice?

Comment: @nevermind I want to add the image; the special-notice was previously empty so I simply rewrite the HTML content